# Divide by zero error

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In my textbook they describe the power method for finding the largest eigenvalue for a nonsingular matrix A. They present the following algorithm

> ```
> input n, A, x, M  
> output 0,x  
> for k=1 to M do  
>     y <- Ax
>     r <- y_1 / x_1
>     x <- y / ||y||
>     output k, x, r
> end do
> ```

There is then an assignment where you should run this algorithm on the following input
$$Z = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}{3} & {2} & {1} \\ {0} & {2} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right], \quad x=(0,0,6)^{T}, \quad M=50, \quad n=3$$

I dont understand how this should work, or if i am misreading the pseudocode?

Comment: $r$ should converge towards the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Kincaid and Cheney is a pretty standard text, which has been pretty thoroughly vetted since it was first published.  Are you sure that you have copied everything down correctly?  Can you please tell us what page(s) you are finding this on?

Comment: Are you sure it is $r \gets y_1/x_1$ and not $r \gets \|y\|_1/\|x\|_1$?

Answer (score 1):

There are two caveats to the algorithm. First is that the starting
vector $x$ should have a non-zero projection on the eigenvector
with the eigenvalue of largest absolute value. The algorithm is
based on the assumption that a geometric progression with constant
ratio the largest absolute value will dominate all of the other geometric progressions with the other eigenvalues assuming
that they have strictly smaller absolute values.
Picking a random starting vector $x$ will almost certainly be
sufficient to avoid the problem.

Second is that
in the limit, the vector $y$ will be a multiple of $x$ with ratio
the desired eigenvalue. That means that any coordinate of $y$ will
approximately be a constant multiple of the same coordinate of $x$.
If the coordinate of $x$ is zero, then division by it is not possible,
so you have to pick a nonzero coordinate (which must exist assuming nonsingular $A$) instead. There can be other variations which work.

Comment: With the norm you lose the sign, that is, you approximate the absolute value of the eigenvalue.

Comment: The Rayleigh quotient $x^TAx/x^Tx$ will give you the eigenvalue including the sign.

Comment: @CarlChristian : Yes, but that additional computation has to be added to the algorithm, preferably organized in a way that avoids duplicate computations.

Comment: @Lutz: Yes, we must replace the search for a nonzero component of $x$ with the statement $r \gets y^Tx$. Since $y = Ax$ and $x$ is normalized this is the only change.